# facebook like button not appearing when online

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-iframe, social-media

Hi my facebook like button not appearing is not appearing online when hosted on my hosting provider but offline in wamp server it is working fine. my code is as follows:-

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FGallantconcept&amp;width=100&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=35&amp;appId=657033221004925" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Anyone can explain why?

Comment: works fine with me! can you share the url where it doesn't work?

Comment: http://www.excube.com.sg/fb.html
It works perfectly in wamp server but when hosted on my server it is not working... :-(

Comment: I see the `Like` button!

Comment: oh my... thanks I will check it out myself and post here if I find the answer.

Comment: seems to be my browser problem

Comment: Do you have an antivirus installed?

Comment: no I don't it is my chrome settings I think

Comment: Ok, the problem is a chrome extension called disconnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a plugin problem for my chrome